# How to return a lazy sequence from a loop recur with a conditional in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, functional-programming

Still very new to Clojure and programming in general so forgive the stupid question.

The problem is:

Find n and k such that the sum of numbers up to n (exclusive) is equal to the sum of numbers from n+1 to k (inclusive).

My solution (which works fine) is to define the following functions:

```
(defn addd [x] (/ (* x (+ x 1)) 2))
(defn sum-to-n [n] (addd(- n 1)))
(defn sum-to-k [n=1 k=4] (- (addd k) (addd n)))
(defn is-right[n k]
  (= (addd (- n 1)) (sum-to-k n k)))
```

And then run the following loop:

```
 (loop [n 1 k 2]
  (cond 
   (is-right n k) [n k]
   (> (sum-to-k n k) (sum-to-n n) )(recur (inc n) k)
   :else (recur n (inc k))))
```

This only returns one answer but if I manually set n and k I can get different values. However, I would like to define a function which returns a lazy sequence of all values so that:

```
(= [6 8] (take 1 make-seq))
```

How do I do this as efficiently as possible? I have tried various things but haven't had much luck.

Thanks

:Edit:

I think I came up with a better way of doing it, but its returning 'let should be a vector'. Clojure docs aren't much help...

Heres the new code:

```
(defn calc-n [n k]
(inc (+ (* 2 k) (* 3 n))))

(defn calc-k [n k]
(inc (+ (* 3 k)(* 4 n))))

(defn f
   (let [n 4 k 6]
      (recur (calc-n n k) (calc-k n k))))

(take 4 (f))
```

Comment: In your edit you're missing the argument vector for `f`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't feel like "rolling your own", here is an alternate solution.  I also cleaned up the algorithm a bit through renaming/reformating.

The main difference is that you treat your loop-recur as an infinite loop inside of the `t/lazy-gen` form. When you find a value you want to keep, you use the `t/yield` expression to create a lazy-sequence of outputs. This structure is the Clojure version of a ***generator function***, just like in Python.

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use tupelo.test )
  (:require [tupelo.core :as t] ))

(defn integrate-to [x]
  (/ (* x (+ x 1)) 2))
(defn sum-to-n [n]
  (integrate-to (- n 1)))
(defn sum-n-to-k [n k]
  (- (integrate-to k) (integrate-to n)))
(defn sums-match[n k]
  (= (sum-to-n n) (sum-n-to-k n k)))

(defn recur-gen []
  (t/lazy-gen
    (loop [n 1 k 2]
      (when (sums-match n k)
        (t/yield [n k]))
      (if (< (sum-to-n n) (sum-n-to-k n k))
        (recur (inc n) k)
        (recur n (inc k))))))
```

with results:

```
-------------------------------
   Clojure 1.10.1    Java 13
-------------------------------

(take 5 (recur-gen)) => ([6 8] [35 49] [204 288] [1189 1681] [6930 9800])
```

You can find all of the details [in the Tupelo Library](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo#generator-functions-for-lazy-sequences-a-la-python).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can create a lazy-seq, so that the next iteration will take result of the previous iteration. Here is my suggestion:

```
(defn cal [n k]
   (loop [n n k k]
     (cond
       (is-right n k) [n k]
       (> (sum-to-k n k) (sum-to-n n) )(recur (inc n) k)
       :else (recur n (inc k)))))

(defn make-seq [n k]
  (if-let [[n1 k1] (cal n k)]
      (cons [n1 k1] 
            (lazy-seq (make-seq (inc n1) (inc k1))))))

 (take 5 (make-seq 1 2)) 
 ;;=>  ([6 8] [35 49] [204 288] [1189 1681] [6930 9800])
```

Comment: Why are you using `if-let`? It seems a plain `let` is all that is required.

Comment: An `if-let` allows for a sequence that terminates, if some future implementation of `cal` can determine that no more answers can ever possibly be found. Compare to, for example, the definition of `take`, which at its core looks like `(defn take [n xs] (lazy-seq (if (zero? n) (), (if-let [coll (seq xs)] (cons (first coll) (take (dec n (rest coll))))))))`.

Comment: yes  like amalloy said, if-let is needed to terminate the lazy-seq

Answer (score 1):

just generating lazy seq of candidatess with `iterate` and then filtering them should probably be what you need:

```
(def pairs
  (->> [1 2]
       (iterate (fn [[n k]]
                  (if (< (sum-to-n n) (sum-n-to-k n k))
                    [(inc n) k]
                    [n (inc k)])))
       (filter (partial apply is-right))))

user> (take 5 pairs)
;;=> ([6 8] [35 49] [204 288] [1189 1681] [6930 9800])
```

semantically it is just like manually generating a lazy-seq, and should be as efficient, but this one is probably more idiomatic

Answer (score 0):

This first function probably has a better name from math, but I don't know math very well. I'd use `inc` (increment) instead of `(+ ,,, 1)`, but that's just personal preference.

```
(defn addd [x]
  (/ (* x (inc x)) 2))
```

I'll slightly clean up the spacing here and use the `dec` (decrement) function.

```
(defn sum-to-n [n]
  (addd (dec n)))

(defn sum-n-to-k [n k]
  (- (addd k) (addd n)))
```

In some languages predicates, functions that return booleans,
have names like `is-odd` or `is-whatever`. In clojure they're usually
called `odd?` or `whatever?`.
The question-mark is not syntax, it's just part of the name.

```
(defn matching-sums? [n k]
  (= (addd (dec n)) (sum-n-to-k n k)))
```

The loop special form is kind of like an anonymous function
for recur to jump back to. If there's no loop form, recur jumps back
to the enclosing function.
Also, dunno what to call this so I'll just call it `f`.

```
(defn f [n k]
  (cond
    (matching-sums? n k) [n k]
    (> (sum-n-to-k n k) (sum-to-n n)) (recur (inc n) k)
    :else (recur n (inc k))))

(comment

  (f 1 2) ;=> [6 8]

  (f 7 9) ;=> [35 49]

  )
```

Now, for your actual question. How to make a lazy sequence. You can use the `lazy-seq` macro, like in minhtuannguyen's answer, but there's an easier, higher level way. Use the `iterate` function. `iterate` takes a function and a value and returns an infinite sequence of the value followed by calling the function with the value, followed by calling the function on *that* value etc.

```
(defn make-seq [init]
  (iterate (fn [n-and-k]
             (let [n (first n-and-k)
                   k (second n-and-k)]
               (f (inc n) (inc k))))
           init))

(comment

  (take 4 (make-seq [1 2])) ;=> ([1 2] [6 8] [35 49] [204 288])
  )
```

That can be simplified a bit by using destructuring in the argument-vector of the anonymous function.

```
(defn make-seq [init]
  (iterate (fn [[n k]]
             (f (inc n) (inc k)))
           init))
```

Edit:
About the repeated calculations in `f`.

By saving the result of the calculations using a `let`, you can avoid calculating `addd` multiple times for each number.

```
(defn f [n k]
  (let [to-n (sum-to-n n)
        n-to-k (sum-n-to-k n k)]
    (cond
      (= to-n n-to-k) [n k]
      (> n-to-k to-n) (recur (inc n) k)
      :else (recur n (inc k)))))
```

Comment: This is what I wanted, however isn't it quite inefficient? If I understand it correctly, you will be repeating a lot of work each time you call f. Is there a way of setting the next value of n and k to their previous values + 1?

Comment: @armincerf `iterate` in itself is not inefficient, in the example the anon function will be called 4 times, each time with the previous value. The `f` function, however, does indeed repeat some calculations.

Comment: @armincerf I've made an edit to my answer. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Ok I think I have a good solution, but can't get it to run... I'm probably doing something dumb, I made an edit and added my code to the question